# couchbase expire time: touch induce concurrent

Tags: couchbase

all! I have a question about `couchbase` expire time. I update the TTL of the item using the function `touch()`.  But the `touch()` can not make `CAS` value changes, should the concurrent be solved? Thanks

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page. What have you tried so far, and what errors/issues have you faced? StackOverflow is not a code-writting service. Code is good - ideally provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `all!` ?? Seriously !?

Comment: the concurrent  is less often , but there is a possibility of occurrence.